# point evaluation cannot be inner product of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we consider the vector space of real-valued continuous functions $V:= C[-1,1]$. Then $\phi(f):= f(0) \; \forall \; f \in V$ is a linear functional.

I want to show that $\phi(f)$ cannot be represented as $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) g(x) dx$ for any $g \in V$.

How would I go about showing this ? I would appreciate some hints, without invoking advanced concepts.

**EDIT** :This problem appears in an exercise on linear algebra, to show that the Riesz Representation Theorem on finite dimensional spaces may not hold on function spaces without additional assumptions. Hence I assume there must be a simple way to show this.

Comment: If you know Radon-Nikodym, then because the Dirac measure is not absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure... Otherwise, consider $0\le f \le 1$ such that it is supported on $[-t,t]$ with $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @user251257: How will that help me show a contradiction ? I had  started with a hat function similar to what you suggested and am stuck.

Comment: the integral would be bounded by a constant times $t$. Now, for $t\to 0$, what happens?

Comment: @user251257:I get  $f(0) =1 \leq  \sqrt{2t} ||g||$ by Cauchy-Schwarz and thus in the limit $1 \leq 0$. which is the contradiction sought. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: basically yes. you don't need Cauchy Schwarz. But if you want to, you should square the left hand side or take the root on the right hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, suppose $\phi(f) = \int f \cdot g$.

Let $r_n$ be the function given by straight line interpolation between the
points $(-1,1), (-{1 \over n},1), (0,0), ({1 \over n}, 1), (1,1))$.

Let $f_n = g r_n$, then
$\phi(f_n) = 0 \ge \int_{[-1,-{1 \over n}] \cup [{1 \over n}, 1]} g^2$, and since
$g$ is continuous, we see that $g = 0$, which gives $\phi = 0$, a contradiction.

Here is another way:

Let $|g(x)| \le B$, then if $\phi(f) = \int f \cdot g$, we have
$\phi(f) \le B \int |f|$.

Now let $f_n = \max(0, 1-n|x|)$, then we have
$\phi(f_n) = 1 \le B {1 \over n}$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction
for large $n$.